# Filter two lists that have same elements to only obtain a list with distinct elements using Java Stream

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream

I have `list1` and `list2` like below

```
List<String> list1 = List.of("DX4555", "DY4897", "FG4333", "IH09992");
List<String> list2 = List.of("DX4555", "DY4897", "FG4333", "IH09992", "LJ48833", "YTR3888");
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a list that only contains elements in list2 that are not in list1 which are unique which are `["LJ48833","YTR3888"]`

I would like to achieve this using Java Stream

I have tried using `stream().distinct()`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream.distinct() only allows you to discard elements that are present multiple times **in the same collection** or **as they are iterated**.

I suggest using [ListUtils.subtract](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html) from apache commons, but you can also do it with streams, like this:

```
List<String> result = list2.stream()
.filter(item -> !list1.contains(item))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice that it's an `O(n^2)` algorithm, due to the fact that List.contains is linear.
If your lists are big, you should replace them with sets to be more efficient.